# Context for reviewing answer posts

Tags: feature-request, review

When reviewing low quality answers, the question is displayed for context. This is nice, but I end up visiting the page as I have to compare with other answers there as well. It would be great if the review page also displayed any other answers that are:

- accepted,
- highest upvoted, or
- awarded bounties

This would help to check:

- if post is a duplicate of existing answers
- incorrect answers
- dangerous spelling mistakes (ie. answer is correct, addresses something useful but no one can make sense of it)

Comment: I definitely support it. I think some more context like: **"This is ranked 37th out of 37 answers, and the first one has 25 upvotes"** helps you quicly assess answer quality. It seems that many of the answers I have reviewed were lowest-quality posts in long lists of answers.

Comment: It already has the question.  If you include all other answers you're showing basically everything on the actual question's page.  The whole point is not to do that, and to provide only the information needed to make a decision for the common cases.  If you need to see the whole question just go to the actual question.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not asking for all answers; only those that meet certain criteria. I have to view the actual question too often for reviewing, and this would cut down the need to do so quite a lot.

Comment: I think the issue is: If the amount of context which is currently displayed is considered by Stackoverflow to be enough to make a judgement, then perhaps a message such as "Answers should be judged objectively. ie: based on whether or not they provide useful information, not how good they are in relation to others." If that is indeed what Stackoverflow wants us to do, that ought to be explicitly stated. If that's not the case, then we need more context. If we're just meant to say either "this is spam", "this is great!", or "this is okay.", the third option shouldn't be phrased "not sure".